# Is there any advice so I can clone the entire thing smoothly next time

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, laptop, cloning

Here is my situation. I have spent days to solve this and now I give up. It is very painful, takes a lot of time, and can break the OS itself. I used to change job after working for 1.5 years or 2 years, and I usually use the same OS with all packages and configurations. I want to clone the OS, the entire thing (not just the /home folder)

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567730/gave-up-waiting-for-root-device-ubuntu-vg-root-doesnt-exist) (with the other more than 30 browser tabs) and still can't solve the problem. Have tried boot-repair, and the list goes on. I didn't sleep for one day to try all of them.

Btw I used Ubuntu 16.04.5, and tried to clone it from Dell Inspiron 15 to Asus FX504. For the first time I can't even use Live USB and need to add something like

> nouveau.modeset=0 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 acpi_osi=Linux
>   i915.preliminary_hw_suppot=1 idle=nomwait

and even I already enter the desktop environment, the touchpad is not working (I think it needs kernel version 4.9.1, and it still used version 3.5). Too much incompatibility and pain! Enough is enough, I will fresh install the OS. But, is there any advice so I can clone the entire thing smoothly next time? For example, what and how to store the package/data, should kernel be updated or the other drivers, problem with full disk encryption and LVM, should we use only apt install, or what to avoid, and so forth.

Comment: You want to clone an OS from one _laptop_ onto another _laptop_? A different one, from a different manufacturer which has completely different hardware?

Comment: You can try cloning an installed system. It will usually work when cloning from one drive to another drive (that is at least as big as the original one), and you use it in the same computer. It will often but far from always work when you use the cloned copy in another computer. It depends on the hardware, which drivers are installed and if they work with the hardware in the other computer. In such cases it is best to make a fresh installation (maybe keep `/home`, which is easy with a 'home' partition). In any case, backup everything important (personal files).

Comment: Is this not a possible case for containers such as docker?  Granted matching that container environment to something that already exists is working backwards....

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is possible, but you need to plan ahead very carefully:

- Buy the highest end computer you can afford (I buy one computer every 7 years)
- Ensure it's upgradeable to at least twice the configuration size you currently have (my previous laptop started with 1G of RAM, 120GB HDD and ended up with 4G / 1TB before it finally broke down)
- Treat the machine with a lot of respect and care so it will survive for as long as possible.
- Choose a distro that has rolling updates instead of forced upgrades¹
- Install a VM in which to try out software (your "test system") and delete it every so often and only install the software that is rock stable *and that you actually need* in your host (your "production system")²
- Install CloneZilla live as a bootable ISO in `grub` and take regular clones of your `/` and your choice of backup software for `/home`.³

  - If the host gets corrupted, restore the previous clone and let the auto-update re-apply all patches.
  - If you upgrade the machine's storage, just restore the clone on another hard drive.  If you upgrade the RAM: change the swap space (if needed for your use case)
  - If you upgrade the entire machine: re-install `/` and restore `/home`.

*Even if you do all the above, eventually you'll have to change again* so prepare your next change and start saving up now for your next computer and look at new computers one year before your current one breaks down.

***What you're trying to do now however*** is cloning an OS customised for one piece of hardware onto another totally different piece of hardware which would be the equivalent of buying a BMW and expecting all of the controls of your old Ford Mustang to be in the same place and retain their current look and feel on your BMW.  *Not going to happen!*

<sub>**Note¹:** If you take a distro that has a long life span for its LTS (Long Time Service) versions you'll need to be prepared to shell out money to get extended support *eventually*.

**Note²:** Don't do what most users do and treat their production system as a test system and install / uninstall Shiny! New! Gizmos! all of the time and expect the system to remain rock solid.

**Note³:** Keep at least the 3 last clones on an external hard drive that is only inserted when you take an off-line backup and choose data backup software that allows versioning and also keep at least 3 versions.</sub>

Comment: +1 *"Treat the machine with a lot of respect and care so it will survive for as long as possible."* Never underestimate how much of a grudge your machine can hold against you... My first laptop chose to burn rather than to stay with me for one more day...